# Backspace is not working in Textarea of My Form on Mozila browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, backspace

```js
function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
  try {
    if (window.event)  {
      var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e) {
      var charCode = e.which;
    }
    else { return true; }
    if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
  catch (err) {
    alert(err.Description);
  }
}

function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}   
       
$('input.facebookUrl').keyup(function(){
  if (
    ($(this).val().length > 0) && ($(this).val().substr(0,24) != 'http://www.facebook.com/')
    || ($(this).val() == '')
  ){
    $(this).val('http://www.facebook.com/');    
  }
});
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="firstname"  class="text_area"  maxlength=20 placeholder="Name" type="text" onKeyPress="return onlyAlphabets(event,this)" required  id="ValidName" value="" />
    </td>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" id="volpincode" maxlength=7 name="pincode"  value="" required  placeholder="Pincode" class="text_area">
    </td>
    <td><input style="width:300px" type="text" onkeypress="return keyup(event)" class="facebookUrl" name="facebook" value="http://www.facebook.com/$facebook"></td>
    <td>
      <input style="width:30px" disabled="disabled" type="text" name="facebook" value="+91" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to validate the Name and Pin code, as such that in the NAME field only the alphabets have to enter not any other characters and In Pincode only numbers should enter. The form is working in Google chrome as fine, but firefox when i enter and try to delete the text in text field, the characters are not getting deleted.

Comment: You might want to just use [native validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) to avoid al these hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate only alphabets for Name use below code:

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#NametextboxID", function (e) {
                if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                } else {

                    var key = e.keyCode;
                    if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90) || (key == 9))) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
```

To validate only numbers for Pin use below code:

```
 $(document).on("keydown", "#PinId", function (e) {
                if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) { // if shift, ctrl or alt keys held down
                    e.preventDefault();         // Prevent character input
                } else {
                    var n = e.keyCode;
                    if (!((n == 8)              // backspace
                            || (n == 46)                // delete
                            || (n >= 35 && n <= 40)     // arrow keys/home/end
                            || (n >= 48 && n <= 57)     // numbers on keyboard
                            || (n >= 96 && n <= 105)
                            || (n == 9))   // number on keypad
                    ) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // alert("in if");
                        // Prevent character input
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more condition to the  "onlyAlphabets function" for the name field.

```
if (charCode == 8 || (charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
```

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d0eq857f/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much, its working.. I have already tired that conditions before, but not implemented properly. Now I understood where to implement that condition.  Thank you

Comment: Now I can'ta able to navigate the fields between the form using TAB key in keyboard. What is conditions to check it??

Comment: check for "charCode == 9"

Comment: I have tired it. The bug is still there...
Please let me know is this condition is proper

 if (charCode == 8 || (charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || charCode == 9)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err.Description);
            }